# Serialize JSONP/JSONPObject in Dropwizard

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I'm able to return JSON response in my Dropwizard resource without any problem. But when I tried to return a JSONPObject, the response still returns a JSON, instead of a JSON wrapped in the callback function requested.

```
@Path("/results")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ExperimentResultResource {

    ...

    @Path("results/{experimentId}")
    @GET
    @Timed
    public Object getResults(
            @PathParam("experimentId") @NotEmpty long experimentId,
            @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {

        ....
        ExperimentResultRepresentation representation = dataSource.queryResults(query);
        if (callback != null) {
            JSONPObject obj = new JSONPObject(callback, representation);
            return obj;
        }
        return representation;
    }
```

The good thing is that, instead of spitting out the original JSON, it did include the `serializationType` and `function` element in the JSON body:

```
{
    "value": { // the original JSON body }
    "serializationType": null,
    "function": "jQuery17209002291325014085_1450240336024"
}
```

I also tried including the `@JSONP` annotation above the method as well. No luck either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONPObject` instead of `org.codehaus.jackson.map.util.JSONPObject`.